# Uparrow with horizontal line below

Tags: arrows

I want to remove the space between the arrow and the underline in `\underline{\Uparrow}`

to obtain a new symbol which consists of an arrow with a horizontal line below, that is, something like this

[image]

how can I do?

Comment: the package `stmaryrd` knows `\Mapsto` which you could rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smash it!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\(\underline{\smash{\Uparrow}}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: And to obtain its Downarrow version? $\overline{\smash{\Downarrow}}$ does not seem to work

Comment: @Littlefield Then it would be easier to follow Jasper's approach. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{-90}{\(\Mapsto\)}
\end{document}`